# Compare two lists in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am working on SharePoint 2010 and need to compare two sites. The comparison has to include the lists within those sites. I need to know if there is anything that I should compare apart from the content of the lists?
Also, what would be the best way to compare two lists?

Comment: What makes two lists equal?  Do you care about settings?  Content types?

Comment: When I am comparing the sites, I will take two similar libraries/lists say the Pages library. then in that case apart from the content, settings can be another thing that I should check. But I dont think content types would be that important

Comment: You would probably need to write a tool app that does the comparison for you.  You could use the client object model and make a desktop app, if you choose, eliminating any need to deploy to the sharepoint server.

Comment: yes that is what I had also thought of. But I am not aware if there is any particular technology say powershell or CAML queries that I should be using for comparison ? Or should it be a combination of them?

Comment: Probably neither.  The Client object model provides access to the lists using objects.  Stand by, I'll post an answer with an example of how to connect to a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a basic example, you'll probably do something a little more complex, especially if you're wanting to use a custom CamlQuery to filter the items, or check the settings of the list.

```
using(ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("http://url.to.site.com/"))
{
    Web web = ctx.Web;
    List list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Pages");
    ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());

    ctx.Load(list);
    ctx.Load(items);

    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

    // after the ExecuteQuery call, list and items will contain references
    // to the lists and the items in the list.
}
```

Make sure you reference `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll` and `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll`.  These can be found in `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\ISAPI` on one of the SharePoint servers in the farm.  Copy them to your project and reference them.

For more information on the client object model, I recommend checking out this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee857094.aspx